# LL(1) parsing conflict

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I'm writing a LL(1) parser for a very simple grammar. Yet I've found conflicts when trying to build the parsing table.

I'm surprised since the grammar seems simple. I don't know if I have a problem with the parser or with my understanding of LL(1) parsing. Maybe the grammar is not LL(1) in the end.

The grammar is:

```
1: S         -> begin list
2: list      -> id    listPrime
3: listPrime -> id    listPrime
4:            | ε
```

My code runs into two conflicts, both for deriving `listPrime`, one with the terminal symbol `id` and one with the `EOF`. In both cases rule 3 clashes against rule 4.

My computed `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets are:

```
first:
   { S: Set { 'begin' },
     list: Set { 'id' },
     listPrime: Set { 'id', 'eps' } },

follow:
   { S: Set { 'EOF' },
     list: Set { 'EOF', 'id' },
     listPrime: Set { 'EOF', 'id' } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar is LL(1). Your FOLLOW sets are computed incorrectly, which can easily be verified: there is no derivation in which `list` or `listPrime` is followed by a token other than `EOF`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck at this, after realizing that FOLLOW was wrong I was able to fix the bugs quickly